# Create a stored procedure to populate a table with one row-Yearly and Monthly Averages

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I have created a stored procedure to populate a log table. I am having trouble with the syntax for columns H and I.  Is there something wrong with my syntax as it relates to monthly and yearly averages? My problem seems to be with those lines of code.

Output ROW
[image]
Stored Procedure

```
   DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE populate()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE NoEmpvar INT;
    DECLARE NoDeptvar INT; 
    DECLARE locregion1var INT; 
    DECLARE locregion2var INT; 
    DECLARE locregion3var INT; 
    DECLARE totalsalesvar DECIMAL(10,2); 
    DECLARE avgsalesvar DECIMAL(10,2); 
    DECLARE avgsalesmovar DECIMAL(10,2); 
    DECLARE avgsalesyrvar DECIMAL(10,2);
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO NoEmpvar FROM  emp; 
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO NoDeptvar FROM dept;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO locregion1var FROM location WHERE regionid=1; 
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO locregion2var FROM location WHERE regionid=2; 
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO locregion3var FROM location WHERE regionid=3; 
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO totalsalesvar FROM sales;
    SELECT AVG(salesamt) INTO AvgSale FROM sales;
    SELECT AVG(salesamt) INTO avgsalesmovar FROM sales WHERE month(salesdate);
    SELECT AVG(salesamt) INTO avgsalesyrvar FROM sales WHERE year(salesdate);
INSERT INTO Log(NoEmp, NoDept, LocReg1, LocReg2, LocReg3, TotSales, AvgSale, AvgSaleMo, AvgSaleYr) 
    VALUES(NoEmpvar,NoDeptvar,locregion1var,locregion2var,locregion3var,totalsalesvar,avgsalesvar,avgsale smovar,avgsalesyrvar);
    END //
```

Comment: If there were a problem with the syntax, the queries wouldn't run at all. They are executing. Do you have any rows in that table with a salesdate in the current month and year of `NOW()`? If there are no matching rows, then `AVG()` returns NULL. Try `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @nowcount FROM sales WHERE month(salesdate)=month(NOW()) AND    year(salesdate)=year(NOW());` Then after the procedure runs, the session variable `@nowcount` will be 0 if there were no matching rows.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was using NOW in the wrong context. I don't need that statement at all.  My sales data covers years 2016 and 2017 so I need to get the average from those months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you dont have any sales in the sales table from this month or year?
If you are confident that you do, maybe just run

select distinct month(salesdate) from sales

and also run

Select month(now())

and just see if there was anything different in your data?

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try that now.  I just realized that I don't have NOW data.  My sales data covers years 2016 and 2017.

Comment: Glad to help! Sometimes it is easy to miss things like that when pulling from tables.